# How many times can a degree $n$ polynomial 'kiss' a strictly concave function?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, convex-analysis

Suppose we are given strictly concave function $g$ on some closed interval $[a,b]$.
We are interesting in answering how many times a degree $n$ polynomial can touch the function $g$ without crossing it.

Formally, let $P_n(g)$ denote set of all polynomial of degree at most $n$ such that $p_n \in P_n$ satisfies $p_n(t) \le g(t)$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ and let
\begin{align}
S(p_n)  = \{ x \in [a,b]:   g(x)=p_n(x) \}
\end{align}

We are interested in
\begin{align}
K (n,g) = \sup_{p_n \in P_n(g)} | S(p_n)|
\end{align}
where $|\cdot|$ denotes cardinality.

To make the problem non-trivial.  *We assume that $g$ is analytic but not   a polynomial.*

**Question:** Can we find upper bounds on $K (n,g) $ as function of $n$?

Here is my thinking and rough calculation: We can first kiss at the end points. So this is two.

So we have $n-2$ more degrees of freedom.

Next, place maxima of the polynomial to touch $g$. We can have now at most $\frac{n-2}{2}$ maxima.

So, it looks like to function can kiss at most $\frac{n-2}{2}+2$ times.

Comment: Well, what if $g$ is polynomial of degree $\leq n$? Then $K(n,g) = \infty$...

Comment: Or $-x^2+\sin x$ touches $-x^2+1$

Comment: @JairTaylor Good point. I mean to void this case. I will add this assumption on $g$.

Comment: The rough calculation does not seem to notice any properties about $g$, in particular, it doesn't seem to distinguish between $g$ being affine $y = mx + b$ or $g$ is a strictly concave function not a polynomial.

Comment: Notice "place the maxima of the polynomial to touch $g$" actually doesn't always achieve what you want (when $g$ is not constant). If a maximum of $f$ is on the graph of $g$, then $f$ will not be tangent to $g$ unless $g'$ is also $0$ there.

Comment: @GregMartin I see. I guess the question is harder than I originally thought. Do you think we have a simple universal bound for strictly concave function (e.g., $n$)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no upper bound. Consider $p(t)=-t^2$ and $g(t) = 1 - \cos t - t^2$. Note that $g''(t) = - \cos t - 2 < 0$ and so $g$ is strictly concave. Yet $p(t) \le g(t)$ everywhere and $p(t) = g(t)$ at infinitely many points, namely every multiple of $2\pi$. (One can scale these functions horizontally so that there are arbitrarily many periods inside any prescribed compact interval.)

Comment: Thanks. Good example!